# Android fix coordinates after scaling canvas by mid point

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, imageview

I have custom class extends from View, where I draw Bitmap and want to 
scale and drag it with limits.
My task is creating ImageView which will be used in gallery, to see full photo.
Now I realized scale and drag but when I began to realize their limitation, noticed that after canvas.scale(mScale, mSсale, mid.x, mid.y) image position changes but my values mX, mY not change.
For this, I began making scale withour mid point, and change mX and mY manually.
So I have a problem with manually changing this values.

My Class:

```
public class ZoomImageView2 extends View {

private File imageFile;
private Bitmap bitmap;

private static final int NONE = 0;
private static final int DRAG = 1;
private static final int ZOOM = 2;
private int mode = NONE;


private PointF start = new PointF();
private PointF mid = new PointF();
private float oldDist = 1f;
private float d = 0f;
private float newRot = 0f;
private float[] lastEvent = null;

private int mX = 0, mY = 0;
private float mScale = 1f;

private Rect clipBounds_canvas;

private Handler mainHadler;

public ZoomImageView2(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mainHadler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
}

public ZoomImageView2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mainHadler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
}

public ZoomImageView2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    mainHadler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (bitmap != null) {
        canvas.save();
        clipBounds_canvas = canvas.getClipBounds();
        Log.w("SCALING_ZOOMIMAGE2", mX + " " + mY + " " + mScale);
        canvas.scale(mScale, mScale);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, mX, mY, new Paint());
        canvas.restore();
    }
}

public void setImageFile(final File imageFile) {
    this.imageFile = imageFile;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            bitmap = BitmapHelper.getINSTANCE().getSampledBitmapFromFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath(), getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels);
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (bitmap.getWidth() >= bitmap.getHeight()) {
                        mStableScale = (float) getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / (float) bitmap.getWidth();
                    } else {
                        mStableScale = (float) getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels / (float) bitmap.getHeight();
                    }
                    mScale = mStableScale;
                    invalidate();
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}

int mOldX, mOldY;
float mOldScale = 1f;
float mStableScale;
float maxScale = 5f;


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            mode = DRAG;
            lastEvent = null;
            mOldX = mX;
            mOldY = mY;
            mOldScale = mScale;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

            oldDist = spacing(event);
            if (oldDist > 10f) {
                midPoint(mid, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
            }

            lastEvent = new float[4];
            lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
            lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
            lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
            lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (mScale < mStableScale) {
                animateScaleTo(false);
            }
            if (mScale > maxScale) {
                animateScaleTo(true);
            }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

            mode = NONE;
            lastEvent = null;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            if (mode == DRAG) {
                mX = (int) ((event.getX() - start.x) / mScale + mOldX);
                mY = (int) ((event.getY() - start.y) / mScale + mOldY);

            } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                float newDist = spacing(event);

                if (newDist > 10f) {
                    mScale = (newDist / oldDist) * mOldScale;
                    mX = (int)-(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels/2 * (mScale -1) - mOldX*mScale);
                    mY = (int)-(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels/2 * (mScale -1) - mOldY*mScale);
                    //TODO!
                }

                if (lastEvent != null && event.getPointerCount() == 3) {

                    //newRot = rotation(event);
                    //float r = newRot - d;
                    //float[] values = new float[9];
                    //matrix.getValues(values);
                    //float tx = values[2];
                    //float ty = values[5];
                    //float sx = values[0];
                    //float xc = (view.getWidth() / 2) * sx;
                    //float yc = (view.getHeight() / 2) * sx;
                    //matrix.postRotate(r, tx + xc, ty + yc);

                }
            }
            break;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

private void animateScaleTo(final boolean forMax) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int waiting = 1;
                if (forMax) {
                    waiting = (int) (100 / ((mScale - maxScale) / 0.05));
                } else {
                    waiting = (int) (100 / ((mStableScale - mScale) / 0.05));
                }
                if (waiting == 0) waiting = 1;
                while (forMax ? mScale >= maxScale : mScale <= mStableScale) {
                    if (forMax) {
                        mScale -= 0.05;
                    } else {
                        mScale += 0.05;
                    }
                    mainHadler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            invalidate();
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(waiting);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}


private void animateTranslateX(final boolean forEnd) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int waiting;
                if (forEnd) {
                    waiting = (int) (300f / (mX - (float) bitmap.getWidth() * mScale));
                } else {
                    waiting = (int) (300f / (float) (mX));
                }
                if (waiting == 0) waiting = 1;
                while (forEnd ? mX > ((float) bitmap.getWidth() * mScale) : mX > 0) {
                    mX -= 5;
                    mainHadler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            invalidate();
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(waiting);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

private void animateTranslateY(final boolean forEnd) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int waiting;
                if (forEnd) {
                    waiting = (int) (300 / (mY - (float) bitmap.getHeight() * mScale));
                } else {
                    waiting = (int) (300 / (float) (mY));
                }
                if (waiting == 0) waiting = 1;
                while (forEnd ? mY > ((float) bitmap.getHeight() * mScale) : mY > 0) {
                    mY -= 5;
                    mainHadler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            invalidate();
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(waiting);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}


private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    point.set(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / 2, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels / 2);
}
```

}

I have problem in place:

```
if (newDist > 10f) {
   mScale = (newDist / oldDist) * mOldScale;
    mX = (int)-(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels/2 * (mScale -1) - mOldX*mScale);
     mY = (int)-(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels/2 * (mScale -1) - mOldY*mScale);
      //TODO!
   }
```

Here I must set values. Now its wrong.

I spend many time to solve this problem. Thanks a lot for help!
Sorry for bad English

Comment: "Now its wrong" - do you mean the wrong value gets set, or you see an error of some kind? What do you see that you judge to be wrong?

Comment: Yes,  wrong value gets set, and bitmap change position wrong.

Comment: So do I correctly understand you are creating thumbnail, or smaller version, of original images?  If not, please describe as best you can what you expect the transformation to do and what it is actually doing.

Comment: No, I open original image and want to scale and drag it. i have minScale, maxScale value. And also want to limit drag. Bitmap must drag only when it zoomed and do not move away from screen.
So for limiting drag, i want to get real X and Y coordinates. But when I canvas.scale image, my X and Y have wrong value.

Comment: for mX and mY, mScale-1 is going to produce a negative number when oldDist is larger than newDist.  10.1f / 15 = .66666667 -1 = -.3333333.  So half your width on mX, let's say 200 becomes -66.66666, which would invert the x, and then if you subtract the (mOldX*.6666667) it becomes an even larger negative number.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: try to write some code base on:
 mScale = (newDist / oldDist) * mOldScale;

Like:
    mX = (int)-(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels/2 * (mScale -1) - mOldX*mScale);

This code make bitmap moves out from screen then scale is big

Comment: What happens if you just mX = (int)-(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels/2 - mOldXmScale); ?  If something is becoming unexpectedly large, it sounds like a multiplier is the culprit.  That's the only one I see there that isn't being subtracted also.

Comment: Yes, thanks! Good result, mX and mY values are corrent, but zoom is always in right bottom angle. But I think I will fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, part of the solution is as follows:  Modify the following:

```
mX = (int)-(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels/2 * (mScale -1) - mOldX*mScale);
mY = (int)-(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels/2 * (mScale -1) - mOldY*mScale);
```

to:

```
mX = (int)-(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels/2  - mOldX*mScale);
mY = (int)-(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels/2 - mOldY*mScale);
```

to remove an unnecessary additional multiplication step, which has the effect of scaling the image to a size that is too large.